# modify item innerXml with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

So I've a little with my PowerShell script and XML file.
Currently the XML file is formated like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings> 
  <ARP>
    <ConfigVLAN>
      <Vlan>Vlan1</Vlan>
      <Vlan>Vlan2</Vlan>
      <Vlan>Vlan3</Vlan>
      <Vlan>Vlan4$</Vlan>
    </ConfigVLAN>
  </ARP>
</Settings>
```

And my Powershell script like this :

```
function modifyXmlItem ($selectedItem, $newValue) {

    $node = $xml.Settings.ARP.configVLAN | where {$_ -eq $selectedItem}
    $node = $newValue
    $xml.Save($path)
}
```

So I want change value of the Vlan1 by a value from a textbox.
I can get value form the textbox, I can get value selected (Vlan 1), but I failed to change the "Vlan1"...

But this function doesn't work ...
I have tried many solution provided from the web but none working...

Can you help me please...
(Sorry for my bad English..)

Comment: What is the expected output given the XML above as input? And show what have you tried so far to achieve such output...

Comment: What is the type of `$selectedItem`? What is in `$node` after first line?

Comment: the type of `$selectedItem` is String. Et `$node` contains the value selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$xml = [xml]'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings> 
  <ARP>
    <ConfigVLAN>
      <Vlan>Vlan1</Vlan>
      <Vlan>Vlan2</Vlan>
      <Vlan>Vlan3</Vlan>
      <Vlan>Vlan4$</Vlan>
    </ConfigVLAN>
  </ARP>
</Settings>'
$selectedItem = 'Vlan4$'

$xml.Settings.ARP.ConfigVLAN.SelectSingleNode("Vlan[text()=""$($selectedItem)""]").InnerText = "NewValue"
$xml.Save('d:\temp\out.xml')
```

Comment: Genial, It Works ! Thanks you so much !